# Check if device is offline with firebase cloud messaging

Tags: json, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

When sending messages via Firebase Cloud Messaging, the repsonse from FCM servers tell about the processing of the Request but not whether it was delivered or not to the device.

So, for offline devices how could we know whether message was delivered?

For example,

> {"multicast_id":7138524052704576147,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1472139369768700%d42090b5d42090b5"}]}1

the above JSON is a response from FCM server for request with time_to_live:0 and priority:'high' but the situation is that device for which I want to receive the message is offline.

Is there any possible way to detect if the device is offline?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you link your FCM API key with Developer Console, you have access to [View FCM statistics and issues](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en). In particular:

> Using FCM Diagnostics, you can troubleshoot messages sent through FCM. You can look up the message(s) by registration token or message ID.
>
> …
>
> You can look up messages sent through Firebase Cloud Messaging with a registration token or message ID.

The [message status](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268#status) returned indicates whether the message was delivered, stored, expired, etc.

Note that this diagnostic tool should only be used if you have a made a recent request. This is what the Developer Console says in the FCM Diagnostics section:

> This is not a real-time diagnostic tool, the data shown may be a few minutes out of date, and is only kept for a few days. If you do not see the data that you were expecting, please try again after a short while.

Comment: looks like google disabled this feature, we can not see it in Google Play Console